# How to select an element brought in through ajax

Tags: jquery

I have a contact form, that when submitted will be processed via ajax. Then when the message is sent an ajax callback function will bring a new file, thank-you.php, in place of the form, within the same div the form was previously.

The thank-you file will also contain validation for any incorrectly completed field attributes (server-side validation). The issue is that if there are any validation errors, I want the visitor to click back to the form, so I have a link

```
<a id="contact_back" href="#">Go back to contact form</a>
```

Which onclick I want to use to bring back the form. But I am not able to select it. I have tried live() but that didn't work, and I don't want to use it anyway. I would much rather use the on() API.

```
$("#contact_back").on("click", function(){
    alert('works');
});
```

But still this also fails to be selected.
So how do you select elements that are brought in through ajax or on the fly?

Answer (score 2):

If the object doesn't exist in the DOM, the event needs to be delegated:

```
$("body").on("click", "#contact_back", function(){
    alert('works');
});
```

Comment: wow, that works great! So will ajax code not go into the DOM? Is this essentially attaching 'on' #contact_back into the DOM?

Comment: You can update the DOM at pretty much any time with ajax or whatever, but if the element doesn't exist, modern versions of jQuery allow you bind and delegate future events.  In fact, I think this is the only real way to do it these days.  .on is deprecated.  Essentially, jQuery creates the event and maintains its id for future use when it actually does show up in the DOM.

Comment: .on is deprecated? I thought bind and live were deprecated, and on is the replacement?

Comment: whoops, sorry, I meant .live and .die

Answer (score 0):

*use event delegation* -  For dynamically created element's

```
$(document).on("click","#contact_back", function(){
    alert('works');
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

Use `.delegate()`:

From [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

> Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the
>   selector, **now or in the future**, based on a specific set of root
>   elements.

Hope this helps!